# For loop for array which should have If condtion c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, for-loop

I have to iterate a array with for loop to find it contains specific words in it and add that in listbox
String[] result= ["vicky","vinay@","google@","hello"]

```
For (l=0 ; l<= result.length; l++)
{
     If(result[l].contains("@")
    {
    Listbox.items.add(result[l]);
     }
}
```

What this does is it gets only first found value I am not getting second value?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The answer will not be same.)

Comment: I am using Ms SQL server

Comment: Then you can remove the <mysql> tag.

Comment: Done bro!! Can u help me on this??

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know SQL Server that well.

Comment: PS. Fix that table formatting. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: @vickyMohan . . . Your question pre-supposes an ordering of the data.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You should have a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

You need an ordering column for your data.  Let me assume that you have one.

First add the new column:

```
alter table t add column id int;
```

Note:  `id` is a *really* bad name for a column that can be `null`.  Then:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by <ordering col>) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set id = (case when col1 = 1 then seqnum end);
```

Strictly speaking, you don't need to update the values when `col1 = 0`, because the default value is `NULL`.  However, in case you want a different value there, I am leaving out the `where col1 = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can *simulate* a partial identity column, but you won't be able to incorporate an actual `IDENTITY` column to the table that works conditionally.

If you just need to update a new column with an incremental value, you can just use a `ROW_NUMBER()` over a filtered `SELECT`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        T.Col1,
        T.ID,
        GeneratedID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -- Determine your order here
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
    WHERE
        T.Col1 IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE C SET
    ID = C.GeneratedID
FROM
    CTE AS C
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like below :

```
 update <table_name> set id=1 where Col1=1;
 update <table_name> set id=null where Col1=0;
```